# Kubernetes YAML file with if-else condition

Tags: kubernetes

I have yaml file which use to deploy my application in all the environments. I want to add some JVM args only for test environment . is there anyway i can do it in YAML file?

here is the yaml

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: rss-site
  labels:
    app: web
spec:
  containers:
    - name: front-end
      image: nginx
      ports:
        - containerPort: 80
    - name: rss-reader
      image: nickchase/rss-php-nginx:v1
      ports:
        - containerPort: 88
      env:
       - name: JAVA_OPTS
         value: "
                -Dlog4j.configurationFile=log4j2.xml
                -Denable.scan=true

                "
```

here i want  `-Denable.scan=true` to be conditional and should add only for Test environment .

I tried following way but it not working and kubernete throwing error `error converting YAML to JSON: yaml: line 53: did not find expected key`

Tried:-

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: rss-site
  labels:
    app: web
spec:
  containers:
    - name: front-end
      image: nginx
      ports:
        - containerPort: 80
    - name: rss-reader
      image: nickchase/rss-php-nginx:v1
      ports:
        - containerPort: 88
      env:
       - name: JAVA_OPTS
         value: "
                -Dlog4j.configurationFile=log4j2.xml
                ${{if eq "TEST" "TEST" }} # just sample condition , it will change
                -Denable.scan=true
                 ${{end }}

                "
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`helm` will do that. In fact, the syntax is almost identical to what you've put, and would be something like this:

```yaml
      env:
       - name: JAVA_OPTS
         value: "
                -Dlog4j.configurationFile=log4j2.xml
                 {{- if eq .Values.profile "TEST" }}
                -Denable.scan=true
                 {{- end }}

                "
```

And you declare via the install package (called a Chart) which profile you want to use (i.e. you set the `.Values.profile` value)

You can check out https://helm.sh/ for details and examples

Comment: You added comma ```,``` end of if condition. do i need comma there or just typo?

Comment: That's a typo. Remove from the comma to the end of that line.

Comment: Ah yep, sorry, I copy-pasted your bit and adapted. I will edit my answer